# How to translate(bengali) tabs, tools etc

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, tools

I like blender alot as it is free and open source for modeling animation which i also like. But the main problem is the language as english is my second language. So is there anything that can translate(Bengali) the GUI, tabs, tools etc?

Comment: I am almost certain there is, but would have to double check. Look at docs.blender.org for now

Answer (score 1):

The language options can be found under Edit > User Preferences, then under the *Interface* category, then near the bottom, under the **Translation** section.

[image]

Sadly, not every language is available. Possibly including yours.

[image]